# Returns 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' ...What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
tickers =['ACLLF','ACNB','ALNPY','AMSF','ANAT','APYRF','ATASY','AWTRF','BCH','BCMXY','BGS','BKMG','BKKLY','BKNIY','ACCO','AHCHY','APAM','ARKAY','BIG','BSMX','CBWBF','CFG','CICHY','CIHKY','CMA','CMC','CVI','CWB.TO','TLT','AGG']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers)
for t in tickers :
    data[t]= yf.download(t,'2018-01-01')['Adj Close']
```

Comment: You should use `data.replace()` not directly editing the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from missing ticker data for BKKLY -- that symbol may be delisted.

You can use this instead to bypass the error:

```
for t in tickers: 
    try: 
        data[t] = yf.download(t,'2018-01-01')['Adj Close'] 
    except ValueError: 
        print(f'{t} has no data for this date range')
```